# VBA ExportAsFixedFormat to PDF doesn't print certain images

Tags: excel, vba, image, pdf, graph

I have a macro that saves a PDF of a certain worksheet.  The macro works as expected sometimes, but other times will exclude pictures and graphs from the resulting PDF, while the text and formatting shows up fine.  The same worksheet will PDF correctly if I go through the File / Print menu and print to PDF.

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Desktop" & "\" & thisTitle & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

What might cause this?  It's interesting since it seems to be intermittent for the same workbook, and not an issue for just saving to PDF.

Comment: Print Object is checked, I should have mentioned that in my question.

Comment: Hmmm this is strange...